# Issue when manipulating index values within an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This piece of code asks a user to input 4 songs then asks how many downloads they each got then outputs the arrays, along with the most downloaded track and the total downloads of the 4 combined tracks.

When manipulating the second index of  the arraay(total downloads) an error occurs. Also when outputting the most downloaded tracks it loops and outputs differenet results when the output is outside the for loop. An example of the error would be;

The most downloaded track is See you again

The most downloaded track is Forget you

The most downloaded track is Forget you

When the actual most downloaded track is Forget you.

It also doesnt allow the totalDownloads to be manipulated:

If the tracks have 3000, 2000, 5000, 8000 downloads respectively.

it would turn the total into 3000200050008000. I understand this is because im adding string values but when I try to convert them into integers an error occurs

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class arrays{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    String[][] array = new String[4][2];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Int totalDownloads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        System.out.println("What is track " + (i + 1));
        array[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many thousands of times has it been downloaded? ");
        array[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextInt() * 1000);
        totalDownloads = totalDownloads + array[i][1];

    }

    sc.close();

    String mostDownloads = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(array[1][1]) >= Integer.parseInt(array[i][1])){
           mostDownloads = array[1][0];
        } else if(Integer.parseInt(array[2][1]) >= Integer.parseInt(array[i][1])) {
              mostDownloads = array[2][0];
        } else if(Integer.parseInt(array[3][1]) >= Integer.parseInt(array[i][1])) {
              mostDownloads = array[3][0];
        } else if(Integer.parseInt(array[4][1]) >= Integer.parseInt(array[1][1])) {
              mostDownloads = array[4][0];



}

    System.out.println("The track downloaded the most is " +mostDownloads);
    System.out.println("The total number of downloads of these 4 tracks was " + totalDownloads + "000");
    System.out.println("The details of the downloads are");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[1]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[2]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[3]));
}

}
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextInt() * 1000);`? It's already an int. Also `array[4][0]` will be out of bounds in an array declared as `String[4][]`. Also `Int` is not a thing. This will not complie

Comment: It doesnt allow me to multiply the result by 1000 because of "incompatible types" therefore i assumed it wasnt an int.

Comment: No your `Array` is a `String` array, so you cannot add an int to it

Comment: I would recommend using a `Map` to link the song and number of downloads

Comment: Could you demonstrate Map in an example. It would be very helpful

Comment: Make use of java as an OO language and create a simple class that holds the track title and the number of downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `array` contains strings, so even the number entered for the downloads must be converted to a string by `String.valueOf()` to be inserted.  
Instead of saving the title of the song with most downloads, save the index in the array.  
The loop index to get the most downloaded cannot exceed the `array.length`. 
The last printing of the details can be made by another loop. 
So check this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] array = new String[4][2];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int totalDownloads = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("What is track " + (i + 1));
        array[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many thousands of times has it been downloaded? ");
        int downloads = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) * 1000;
        array[i][1] = String.valueOf(downloads);
        totalDownloads += downloads;
    }

    sc.close();

    int mostDownloadsIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(array[i][1]) > Integer.parseInt(array[mostDownloadsIndex][1]))
            mostDownloadsIndex = i;
    }

    System.out.println("The track downloaded the most is " + array[mostDownloadsIndex][0]);
    System.out.println("The total number of downloads of these 4 tracks was " + totalDownloads);
    System.out.println("The details of the downloads are");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
    }
}
```